# How can I install PHP 5.56 on Amazon Linux 2 CentOS7?

Tags: php, amazon-ec2, centos7

When I run `sudo yum install php56` on my centos7 ec2 instance, the actual version installed is 5.4.

```
Installing:
php                x86_64      5.4.16-46.amzn2.0.2       amzn2-core      1.4 M
php-cli            x86_64      5.4.16-46.amzn2.0.2       amzn2-core      2.8 M
```

I canceled that and tried an archive `sudo yum install --enablerepo=ius-archive php56u` and got an dependency error:

```
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: php56u-common-5.6.40-1.ius.el7.x86_64 (ius-archive)
       Requires: php56u-pecl-jsonc(x86-64)
       Available: php56u-pecl-jsonc-1.3.6-2.ius.el7.x86_64 (ius-archive)
           php56u-pecl-jsonc(x86-64) = 1.3.6-2.ius.el7
       .....
```

How do I resolve that package?

I have considered building php 5.6 from source using [steps from this site](https://blacksaildivision.com/php-install-from-source) but it is quite long and complicated and I am not an expert. I would rather figure out how to fix the dependency error above.

Any other ideas on how I can get php 5.5+ (I cannot do php7) on this Amazon Linux 2 machine?

Comment: You have to remove all the existing PHP packages first. `yum remove php*`

Comment: Also _everything_ below PHP 7.2 is EOL, and 7.4 is current. Don't shackle yourself to PHP5. https://www.php.net/supported-versions.php

Answer (score 3):

I 'fixed' my issue, though not by installing php 5.6. In the end I realized I was spending alot of time trying to get old unsupported code when I could instead spend that time making my code work with php 7/Maria - something I would eventually have to do anyways. Yes, it's taken a few days to work out the kinks, but it's time well spent. Adios PHP5.

I won't mark this as an answer since it doesn't directly address the challenge.

Answer (score 0):

IUS is not compatible with Amazon Linux.  Anything that happens to work is pure luck and should not be counted on.

https://ius.io/faq#is-ius-compatible-with-amazon-linux